# Node.js - How to keep describing Cloudwatch log queries for Completed status of a specific query

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

So for anyone familiar with CW Logs..this is not the typical DB query call that returns with results.
You send an API call to start a query, that returns a Query ID.
You then send a different API call to get the query results, with the "hope" that the query completed, and if it hasn't, you're out of luck.
That's where I am right now.

I have a query that takes a bit of time and I'm "guessing" the way to handle this is to keep looping the DescribeQueries call until I find a match among that returned array of Completed queries, then go on with the rest of the code. I am unable to pull this off! Grrrr!!

I have tried While and Do..While loops that completely do NOT work. I tried setting the escape condition value when a match is found.. but it never gets set and the Lambda function times out.

```
function checkQueryStatus (logGroup, qID, callback) {

      var params = {
      logGroupName: logGroup, 
      maxResults: '3',
      status: 'Complete'
    };

let found = 0;

      do {
      cwlogs.describeQueries(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else {
          // console.log(data.queries);           // successful response
            const qList = data.queries;
            if (qList.some(query => query.queryId === qID)) {  
              console.log('Query Done');
              callback(1);
              found = 1;
          } else {
            console.log('Query not done');
          }
        }
      });
      } while (found == 0); 
}

checkQueryStatus(logGroupName, queryID, function(qStatus) {
  console.log('Query Status: ', qStatus);

  if (qStatus == 1) { 
  console.log('Query Done');

  <do other code...>
```

How can I do it? I'm now looking into Promises to see what thats all about..
If the DescribeQueries find a match, I want to trigger the GetQueryResults API call.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem with AWS Athena. When I start a query, I get back the response that is has started but get no notification when it finishes. The best solution I came up with was to use setTimeout to check its status every 100ms or so and continue when the query is completed. Hope that helps.

Comment: Trying that as well. Works with a hard timeout. Not a looped one. But I'm new to Node so I may be doing it wrong.. any snippet you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function which you can use to await until the query finish and returns the query result.

```
async function queryCloudWatch(queryRequest: StartQueryRequest): Promise<GetQueryResultsResponse> {
    const queryResponse: StartQueryResponse = await cloudwatchLogs.startQuery(queryRequest).promise()

    if (!queryResponse.queryId) return {}

    let response: GetQueryResultsResponse | undefined = undefined

    while (!response || response.status === 'Running') {
        response = await cloudwatchLogs.getQueryResults({
            "queryId": queryResponse.queryId
        }).promise()
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options : query log Insights or query log groups 
If you would like to query log Insights :

Use *cloudwatchlogs.startQuery* and *cloudwatchlogs.getQueryResults* APIs
A very good example can be found at https://gist.github.com/zenoyu/f63799a9079a5df376d5daf3cea27be4

To query log groups use *filterLogEvents* API :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'));
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});
const cloudWatchLogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs({apiVersion: '2014-03-28'});

const timestamp = new Date();
const endtTime = timestamp.getTime();
const params = {
    endTime: endtTime,
    filterPattern: `"${stringToSearch}"`,
    startTime: new Date (endtTime - 5 * 60 * 60* 24 * 1000).getTime(), // Last 5 days
    logGroupName: 'myLogGroup',
    limit : 10
};

const events = await cloudWatchLogs.filterLogEvents(params).promise();
console.log(`successfully queryCloudWatchLogs ${stringToSearch} results: ${JSON.stringify(events)}`);
const results = events.events.map(e => e.message)
console.log(`successfully queryCloudWatchLogs ${stringToSearch} results (${results.length}): ${JSON.stringify(results)}`);
```